# Can a diffeomorphism not be an immersion or a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This may be a stupid question, but I have not seen anywhere that it is  said that a diffeomorphism must be an immersion and a submersion. Therefore I am asking the following two questions:

(I) Is a diffeomorphism between smooth manifolds necessarily a submersion?

(II) Is a diffeomorphism between smooth manifolds necessarily an immersion?

(III) If either (I) or (II) aren't true, can someone help by giving a counter example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the derivative of a diffeomorphism at every point is bijective, every diffeomorphism is both a submersion and an immersion.

Comment: Just one further question if I may, are two diffeomorphic smooth manifolds essentially the same object in an appropriate category?

Comment: Yes: in the category of differentiable manifolds.

Comment: why is the deriviative of a diffeomorphism bijective?